# IIS 6 Extensionless URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I am attempting to do some domain redirects on one of the sites on my server (Server 2003, IIS6), but the Extensionless URLs feature of .Net 4 keeps tacking on that eurl.axd/GUID before the redirect. I found some info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086066/asp-net-mvc-eurl-axd-errors).

I would just disable this feature, as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/06/18/how-to-disable-the-asp-net-v4-0-extensionless-url-feature-on-iis-6-0.aspx), but I am pretty sure this will impact an MVC .Net site I also have set up in IIS (because MVC uses extensionless URLs).

Can someone please assist me in finding other options? Is there a way to just remove the eurl.axd/GUID from the URL, via an IHttpModule? I haven't been able to find an example of anyone doing this or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to have fixed things on my own. Originally I had both my websites set up in IIS under the same App Pool. I separated them into different app pools, made sure they were both set to .Net 4, and everything started working. Now when users are redirected from one domain to another, the eurl.axd/GUID does **not** get tacked on to the end of the URL.