# eurl.axd redirect error when https domain assigned to IIS7.5 website

Tags: https, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, asp.net-4.0

We have a website that was recently updated from ASP.NET 2 on IIS6 to .Net 4 on IIS7.5.
When we deployed to the new Production server, we started getting http 404 errors after people logged in.  I.e. users could see the default login page, but once authenticated the website would crash.  As the URL had been modified to include the eurl.axd components we thought maybe it was something to do with ASP.NET v4 (as per everyone elses issues with this error).  Except everyone having this issue is working with MVC whereas this website is MVP.

So we rolled the code back to the old server while I looked into it.  Now I've got them to redeploy the same code to the Production server again, but had them point the test domain to it for testing purposes.  The website is working just fine.

So the only difference is that when accessed via http, the website works fine.  But if you assign it a https URL, then the post-authentication redirect crashes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem when moving from 3.5 to 4.0 Framework on IIS 6.  We would see this problem whenever you redirected back to the parent url ie www.somewhere.com/

By adding this into the registry of the web server it stopped the eurl.axd from being injected.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0]
"EnableExtensionlessUrls"=dword:00000000
```

Check over here too [ASP.net 4.0 default.aspx problem on IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635320/asp-net-4-0-default-aspx-problem-on-iis6) this details the same issue as well.